# generating a data frame based on a QQ plot

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I am generating a QQ-plot of observed vs. theoretical p-values. But I want to add a vector of the reference line as a column in the original data frame containing a vector of p-values, I also want to add a columns of observed and expected p-values.

```
#data frame with p-value column labeled p-vals)
PVAL<-runif(10000)
pvals<-as.data.frame(PVAL)

#sort the p-values in PVAL and take the negative log
observed <- sort(pvals$PVAL)
lobs <- -(log10(observed))

#generate expected pvalue vector
expected <- c(1:length(observed)) 
lexp <- -(log10(expected / (length(expected)+1)))

#generate QQ plot
#plot red reference line and observed vs expected pvalues
plot(c(0,7), c(0,7), col="red", lwd=3, type="l", xlab="Expected (-logP)", ylab="Observed (-logP)", xlim=c(0,7), ylim=c(0,7), las=1, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", bty="l")
points(lexp, lobs, pch=23, cex=.4, bg="black")
```

The plot works just fine, however, I want a final dataframe that includes columns corresponding to PVAL for "observed", "expected" and the red reference line value vector.

Essentially I want a new dataframe with 4 columns that looks like this:

```
$new_pvals
PVAL    OBSERVED    EXPECTED    RED_REFERENCE_LINE
```

NOTE: PVAL and OBSERVED columns should be the same as one is just a sorted version of the other.

Can someone please help with this? Thanks.
This is to help me see how many points in observed and expected fall under certain values in the reference line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** - as requested, a method of counting the points below (x,x)

```
getpoint<-function(obs,exp){
  ceiling(max(obs,exp))
}
df$nextpoint<-apply(df,1,FUN=function(x)getpoint(x["OBSERVED"],x["EXPECTED"]))
require(plyr) # for count function
count(df$nextpoint) # note e.g. nextpoint = 4 means points below 4,4

x freq
1 1 9000
2 2  900
3 3   90
4 4    9
5 6    1
```

Because your reference line is proportional, I think that if RED_REFERENCE_LINE refers to a Y value, it's equal to `lobs`, if X, it's equal to `lexp`, no?

See below to produce the data frame and give the same graph. Also, once you've produced the dataframe, I don't think you need the RED_REFERENCE_LINE coords - you can just use:     `df<-df[df$OBSERVED<df$EXPECTED,]` to select the points below the 'line'

```
#data frame with p-value column labeled p-vals)
PVAL<-runif(10000)
pvals<-as.data.frame(PVAL)

#sort the p-values in PVAL and take the negative log
observed <- sort(pvals$PVAL)
lobs <- -(log10(observed))

#generate expected pvalue vector
expected <- c(1:length(observed))
lexp <- -(log10(expected / (length(expected)+1)))

#generate QQ plot
#plot red reference line and observed vs expected pvalues
plot(c(0,7), c(0,7), col="red", lwd=3, type="l", xlab="Expected (-logP)", ylab="Observed (-logP)", xlim=c(0,7), ylim=c(0,7), las=1, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", bty="l")
points(lexp, lobs, pch=23, cex=.4, bg="black") 

###########################################################
### DATA FRAME CREATED AND PLOTTED HERE                 ###
###########################################################

df<-data.frame(PVAL=PVAL)
df$OBSERVED<-lobs
df$EXPECTED<-lexp
df$RED_REFERENCE_LINE_Y<-df$EXPECTED

plot(c(df$RED_REFERENCE_LINE_Y,7), c(df$RED_REFERENCE_LINE_Y,7), col="red", lwd=3, type="l", xlab="Expected (-logP)", ylab="Observed (-logP)", xlim=c(0,7), ylim=c(0,7), las=1, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", bty="l")
points(df$EXPECTED, df$OBSERVED, pch=23, cex=.4, bg="black")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. But I am not trying to select points below the line. I am trying to count the number of points below or above the reference line. For example I'd want to know how many expected and how many observed points fall below coordinates (1,1) on the red reference line, then how many fall from (1,1) to (2,2), then how many from (2,2) to (3,3) on the reference line..etc. Is that clearer?